# How can I access the "Documents" section on an IceWarp server using python?

Tags: python, linux

My internet provider uses [IceWarp](https://www.icewarp.com/) as an interface to my mails, notes, documents (and stuff) on their server. I'd like to use the Documents section to exchange files with my computer without having to resort to a web browser. Therefore I'd like to use Python scripts.

Can it be done at all and, if yes, where can I find hints? I know the product is proprietary so I don't expect tons of documentation to be freely available.

Answer (score 1):

Probably no need to script it, there's an app from the vendor that is supposed to do the file synchronization between server and your computer. See [IceWarp FileSync](https://www.icewarp.com/downloads/)!

If you still want to script it, the most flexible approach would be through [WebDAV protocol](http://www.webdav.org/specs/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I asked about scripting because I need a certain amount of tasks to be run on the command line as I already have some scripts ready, which I'd have liked [what I'm looking for] to integrate with. Besides I only reluctantly install proprietary applications on my computer, hence my question. on the other hand I have no information from my provider how WebDAV access can be made, I guess they're as reluctant to give out any such detail... That leaves very few possibilities.